# Is there any way to close idle socket.io connections for too long?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, libwebsockets

Is there any way to close idle socket.io connections ? or I need to track from my client side. My socket.io version is 4.4.1

Answer (score 0):

I have done by using setInterval and if he is idle for too long then I have closed connection by calling socket.disconnect()